# Help checking BackgroundImage

Tags: c#, .net

I am using this code to check a backgroundimage:

```
 if (actionbox1.BackgroundImage == "WaterforMGC.strollinstu.png")
```

But I get the error Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Drawing.Image' and 'string'

So how can I check the BackgroundImage property?

Just in case, here's my randomizing code:

```
        //actionbox1
        var imageNames = new List<string> { "WaterforMGC.strollinstu.png", "WaterforMGC.blank.png", "WaterforMGC.swoopinstu.png", "WaterforMGC.waterbottle.png", "WaterforMGC.goop.png", "WaterforMGC.blank.png" };
        var rand = new Random();
        var index = rand.Next(0, imageNames.Count - 1);
        var s = this.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(imageNames[index]);
        actionbox1.BackgroundImage = Image.FromStream(s);
```

Comment: You can't compare a string to an image. You have to either save the path of the image that you've loaded in so that you're comparing two strings, or load the image pointed to by the path first so that you're comparing two images.

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be simply first load, folowing your example, `WaterforMGC.strollinstu.png`
file into `System.Drawing.Image` object, and after assign it to the `actionbox1.BackgroundImage`.

At the moment when you wnat to figure out the exact image, should be enough to check equality between two objects (which actually will call `GetHashCode()`)

Example:

```
   //somewhere in the code 
   Image img1 = Image.FromFile(@".\.\....\\.\WaterforMGC.strollinstu1.png"); 
   Image img2 = Image.FromFile(@".\.\....\\.\WaterforMGC.strollinstu2.png");

   //assign to back image IMG1
   actionbox1.BackgroundImage = img1;



  //when comes moment to check whcih image is assigned (base on your app logic) 
  if(actionbox1.BackgroundImage == img1) 
  {
     //do somethinmg here, based on your logic
  }
  else if(actionbox1.BackgroundImage == img2) 
  {
     //do somethinmg other, based on your logic
  }
```

Hope this helps.

Regards.

Comment: umm...Please explain more. I'm kind of a n00b